# Can I compile code in C++ Builder 5 for use on Windows 7 (32 and 64 bit) machines?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, c++builder

I have an application which I wrote using C++ Builder 5. Is there any way I can compile this code to run on Windows 7 machines? Preferably for 32-bit and for 64-bit versions.

Comment: You are 13 years, 11 versions and 32 bits behind the times.  You cannot get a warranty here, it expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An app written in BCB5 will run just fine on Windows 7 (I still write apps in BCB6 and they work fine), but if you want to take advantage of modern OS features (manifests, new APIs, shell extensions, etc), you have to manage that code manually, you don't have all of the advances in VCL technology to handle that for you.

That being said, BCB5 only supports 32bit development, so your apps will require WOW64 installed in order to run on 64bit systems.